# AP Calculus BC MCQ question about Power series more specifically the convergence and divergence of the series at endpoints where one endpoint is given

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So this question

[image: Picture of Question]

came up on an AP Calculus BC MCQ and I am not sure why I got it wrong as the answer collegeboard has is B while I put C. The question gives a power series and two points where it is convergent and divergent. Based on the information given, since it diverges at x=9, the maximum the radius of convergence can be is 5 and the minimum it can be is 3 since it converges at x=7. This means that it is not a guarantee that the power diverges at x=-1 since that could be the endpoint of the interval that is convergent or not apart of the interval of convergence at all. Since the minimum of the radius of convergence must be 3 which would mean the interval of convergence is from 1 to 7 since it is centered at x=4 and this interval includes 2, so the power series has to be convergent at x=2. But where I am confused is for statement I, because since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(3)^n$ converges as this is the series at x=7 (which is stated by the problem) it must be a guarantee that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(-3)^n$ will also converge which is the power series at x=1, so I don't understand how only Statement II is true. I think the rationale of the question is that we don't know the convergence of the series at the endpoint of the interval of convergence which makes sense but given the information we have we can prove convergence at x=1 because we know it converges at x=7 right? Please feel free to point me out if I am thinking something incorrectly/not seeing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the series
$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x-4)^n}{3^nn}.
$$
It converges at $x=7$,
$$
S(7)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}=\ln 2,
$$
but diverges at $x=1$:
$$
S(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=-\infty.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence may well be $3$, in which case the series might converge at $x=7$ and diverge at $x=1$. Their answer is correct. I leave it to you to make up example illustrating this possibility.